# Adding Dropout Layers to U_Net Segmentation_Models

Tags: python, image, keras, image-segmentation, dropout

I am using U_Net segmentation model for medical images segmentation with Keras and Tensorflow 2. I'd like to add a dropout layer to the model, but I don't know where to add it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes there isn't dropout layers in the implementation of unet, but you can use regularizers

```
set_regularization(model, kernel_regularizer=keras.regularizers.l2(0.001),bias_regularizer=keras.regularizers.l2(0.001))
```

you can also try data augmentation. But if it is necessary to add dropout you can stop after some layers and add after it the dropout layers you want like this:

```
model = sm.Unet(......)
model_input = model.input
model_output = model.get_layer('final_conv').output (any layer you want)
#add dropout
model_output = keras.layers.Dropout(0.3)(model_output)
#add activation
output = keras.layers.Activation(activation, name=activation)(model_output)
model_dp = keras.models.Model(model_input, output)
```

Comment: Thank you . . I am building my own Unet not using the already built one from TF. So can I add it after any layer? and in encoder and decoder?